# taking address of temporary [-fpermissive] by taking adress of a struct to pointer to struct of other type

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have defined two different typedef structs: datatype_2d_1 and datatype_2d_2, both of them have basically two double numbers as members, but they are differently defined. Now I have a variable datatype z1 and a pointer datatype_2d_2 *z2 and I want that z2 points to the members of z1. The problem arises due to interfacing two different library datatypes.

My code looks as follows:

```
// ** test3.cpp **

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct {
    double dat[2];
} datatype_2d_1;

typedef struct {
    double real;
    double imag;
} datatype_2d_2;

int main(){


        datatype_2d_1 z1={{1.1,2.1}};
        datatype_2d_2 *z2;

        z2=( &(datatype_2d_2) {.real=z1.dat[0],.imag=z1.dat[1]} );

        printf("\n\nz1.dat[0]=%lf\tz1.dat[1]=%lf\n",(z1).dat[0],(z1).dat[1]);
        printf("(*z2).real=%lf\t(*z2).imag=%lf\n",z2->real,z2->imag);
        return 0;
}
```

When compiling with `g++ test3.cpp -o test3`

I get the error:

**taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]**

Comment: The members of your second struct aren't pointers. They can't "point to" anything. I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Roughly speaking z2 should 'point' to z1, such that if I change the values of z1.dat[0] and z1.dat[1], also z2->real and z2->imag are changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your structures have the same memory layout, you can make `z2` just a pointer to `z1`.

```
datatype_2d_1 z1={{1.1,2.1}};
datatype_2d_2 *z2;

z2 = (datatype_2d_2*)&z1;

printf("nz1.dat[0]=%lf\tz1.dat[1]=%lf\n",(z1).dat[0],(z1).dat[1]);
printf("(*z2).real=%lf\t(*z2).imag=%lf\n",z2->real,z2->imag);
```

Or if you could use a union so you can always access the same data in either format:

```
union data_both
{
    datatype_2d_1 a;
    datatype_2d_2 b;
};

datatype_2d_1 z1={{3.1,4.1}};

data_both both;

both.a = z1;

printf("both.a.dat[0]=%lf\tz1.dat[1]=%lf\n",both.a.dat[0],both.a.dat[1]);
printf("both.b.real=%lf\tboth.b.imag=%lf\n",both.b.real,both.b.imag);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
datatype_2d_2 tmp = { .real = z1.dat[0], .imag = z1.dat[1] };
z2 = &tmp;
```

If you want that z2 points to z1 you can try this:

```
 z2 = (datatype_2d_2*)&z1;
```

Comment: The problem here is, that If I change the values of z1, say z1.dat[0]=3.3, than z2->real remains unchanged. In your solution, z2 points to the adress of tmp, but not to the adresses of the members of z1.